# Meaning of unary `&` applied to union member

Tags: c, unions, strict-aliasing

Normally, in C, using the unary `&` operator on an lvalue yields a pointer such that, at any time within the lifetime of the underlying object, applying a unary `*` to the pointer will yield an lvalue equivalent to the original.  Such behavior is essentially the *meaning* of the `&` operator.

In gcc, however, the pointer yielded by applying `&` to a union member does not seem to be usable for any noticeable period of time.  For example, given:

```
struct s1 {int x;};
struct s2 {int x;};
union u {struct s1 v1; struct s2 v2;};

int test(union u *u1, union u *u2)
{
    struct s1 *p1 = &u1->v1;
    if (p1->x)
    {
        struct s2 *p2 = &u2->v2;            
        p2->x = 5;
    }
    p1 = &u1->v1;
    return p1->x;
}
int test2(void)
{
    struct s2 s = {1};
    union u u1;
    u1.v2 = s;
    return test(&u1,&u1);
}
```

gcc will generate code for test1 that returns 1, rather than 5, unless
-fno-strict-aliasing is employed.  Note that `p1->v1.x` and `p2->v2.x` are
both part of the same Common Initial Sequence, a complete union definition
is visible everywhere they are accessed, and the lvalue `p1->v1` is used
between the write of `p2->v2.x` and the succeeding read ("inspection") of `p1->v1.xp`.  If applying the address-of operator to a union member isn't guaranteed to yield a pointer that can be used to inspect the lvalue identified thereby, what does the operator mean?

Comment: To start with: `p1` and `p2` alias each other, but point to different types. Your code violates the effective type rule, thuis invokes UB. I'm not in the mood to search for all paragraphs of the standard involved, but you should be able to find them from here.

Comment: FWIW in MSVC `test2()` returns `5`.

Comment: @Olaf: If the pointer yielded by taking a union member's address can't be used to access that member in cases where the member access would be defined, what is the meaning of applying the "address-of" operator to a union member?  The Standard explicitly says that if a union contains two or more structures that share a common initial sequence, any of those members my be used to inspect members of that common initial sequence.  The complete union type definition is visible everywhere in the above code.

Comment: @WeatherVane: My interpretation of the standard would suggest that behavior of the above code is defined (as yielding 5), but the authors of gcc seem to take a contrary view.  If a compiler treated writes a one union member as invalidating pointers to other union members, that might be understandable, but in the above code the inactive member's address is taken *after* the last access to the active member.

Comment: @Olaf: When `test` is called from `test2`, is there any sense in which `*u1` or `*u2` does not have an actual declared type of `union u`?  Is there any way in which `u1->v1` does not have a declared type of `struct s1`, or `u2->v2` does not have a declared type of `struct s2`?  Under C89, writing one union and reading another was *generally* Implementation-Defined behavior, and outside of Standard-defined cases like CIS accesses, implementations could define that behavior as yielding Unspecified or Indeterminate Value outside of certain specific usage patterns.

Comment: @supercat: You don't use "any union member", but pointers to two _different_ structures. `p1` and `p2` are not pointers to `union`! In C the type is specified by the expression to access it, not the _actual_ type of an object. Said that: did you try the same eliminating `p1,2` and using `u1,2` directly?

Comment: @supercat: Thinking twice, I'm very confident we had this question already here. If you are really interested, you should search for it. Not sure if there was an artificial example like your's, though, could have been some real-world code.

Comment: @Olaf: Union members are regarded by the Standard as objects whose lifetime is that of the enclosing union.  If an lvalue expression `unionPtr->membername` did not identify an object, any use thereof would be Undefined Behavior.  Is there something in the Standard that would regard union members as objects whose lifetime is that of the expression wherein the member-access operator is applied?  That might make some sense, but I see nothing in the Standard that says that.

Comment: @supercat: Where did I talk about lifetime? It is about types. Read my previous comments again. `p1,2` are **not** to unions, but tweo different types. The compiler must not care whether they point to the same memory location. From the compiler's view they point to different objects. Your aliasing invokes UB.

Comment: @Olaf: Within test, what is the type of lvalue `u1->v1`?  What is the type of pointer `&u1->v1`?  It might make sense for the Standard to say that `u1->v1` would behave as an lvalue of its under certain circumstances, but isn't "really" such an lvalue, but I know of nothing in the Standard that would justify a distinction between code which accesses `u1->v1`, code which accesses `*(&u1->v1)`, or code which copies `&(u1->v1)` to an otherwise-unused pointer of type `struct s1*` and dereferences that.

Comment: Obviously `&u1->v1` has type `struct s1 *`. Which other type would it have? Why should the standard provide a special rule for all different variants, if a general rule does apply already? You only refer to `s1` etc, but completely forget `p2` is `struct s2 *`, not `struct s1 *`. As always, it is not clear what your problem is. The compiler is right assuming they don't alias.

Comment: @Olaf: In what contexts would a compiler be required to impart any meaning whatsoever to the Common Initial Sequence rule, and what in the Standard would justify treating such contexts differently from the above code, unless there's something special about the type of `u1->v1` which gets lost when its address gets stored to `p1`.

Comment: The GCC documentation makes it very clear that unions are special (type punning explicitly allowed). And unions means member access then access. Taking a pointer is no no if you want that special GCC behavior. (Nowhere it is written, just implicit.) Union is like food in seal containers, once open, consume immediately. Once you get a lvalue with member access operator on union, write to it immediately. Or something.

Comment: @curiousguy: My code does perform a lvalue conversion upon the union member, using the member-access operator.  If applying the address-of operator to an lvalue does not yield something that can be used in the ways the lvalue can be used in the absence of any other accesses to the underlying object, what's it for?

Comment: @supercat You assume that the adresse-of operator can be used on a union member that is not "active" (yet). I don't think this is possible with the strict typing semantic where unions must have super power. With this strict typing, memory regions get an effective type when written to that cannot be changed willy nilly. (It is obviously possible with the weak typing (old school?) semantic where unions are simple devices to ensure alignment and sweet syntax.)

Comment: @curiousguy: Is there anything in the C Standard which limits the address-of operator to an "active union member", or even defines what such a phrase would mean?  If there were a C offshoot which regarded union members as lvalues but not objects (similar to bitfields) and which specified that once storage has been accessed using a type it may not be used as any other within its lifetime unless a "scrubbing" directive is used, such a language could allow many more optimizations than are possible under C's Effective Type rules, but C presently defines union members as objects.

Comment: @supercat Delicate subject, like walking on thin ice. "_Is there anything in the C Standard which limits the address-of operator to an "active union member_" Nope. Nothing. More like a deduction based on these ideas that 1) there is something special with unions 2) once you take the address of a member the information about the union is gone.

Comment: @curiousguy: The essence of aliasing optimizations is that they re-order and consolidate writes and reads; when the Standard was written, the most common such optimization was moving a read forward in time to match an earlier access to the same lvalue, but other reorderings are also possible. A compiler can't move a read to coincide with a previous read unless it can see that there was no possible conflicting operation involving the type in question, and should have no difficulty recognizing the act of taking a union member's access as indicating a possible conflict if it occurs...

Comment: ...between operations the compiler would like to consolidate.  The usefulness of the CIS guarantee stems mainly from the ability to have functions accept pointers to any structure type containing a CIS, and inspect members of that CIS of all such structures interchangeably.  An assumption that a function which is passed the address of a union member might access CIS members of all other objects in the union should hardly be viewed as pessimistic.